# Expanding SQL database table

Tags: powerquery

The following code pulls all databases on a given server, which works fine.  When I try to expand all the databases by clicking the expand button on the data column, it fails because I do not have access to all the databases.  I tried a number of ways, like adding a column with Table.IsEmpty, but nothing I tried works.

How can I filter out the databases to which I do not have access?  This is important so that the query will update as the access changes.

`let
    Source = Sql.Databases("server", [HierarchicalNavigation=true])
 in
    Source`

Answer (score 0):

I would grit my teeth and use the "try" expression followed by "if ... then ... else". It's described quite well (for once) in the M/PQL doco:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt186368.aspx

I say "grit my teeth" because raw coding in M/PQL is a merciless task. I remember coding in the '80s - it wasn't as hard as raw coding in M/PQL (although your big hair did sometimes obscure the CRT).

I would first generate an example of a successful expand using the UI, by manually filtering the database list to some that you know will work, then hitting Expand.

I would insert the try on the line that is failing, then add the "if ... then ... else" on the next line.